# Getting rid of empty namespaces

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lab="urn:oid:7.6">
    <section>
        <id extension="something" root="testRoot"/>

        <text>
            <paragraph styleCode="somestyle">Soemthing</paragraph>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th styleCode="styled">Style</th>
                        <th>Stuff</th>                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </text>

    </section>

</Test>
```

and this is the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:c="urn:hl7-org:v3"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "c:section/ c:text">
        <text>
            <status value="generated"/>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </text>     
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Test>
    <section>
        <id extension="something" root="testRoot"/>

        <text><status value="generated"/><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <paragraph xmlns="" styleCode="somestyle">Soemthing</paragraph>
            <table xmlns="">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th styleCode="styled">Style</th>
                        <th>Stuff</th>                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div></text>

    </section>

</Test>
```

As you might expect, I don't want any of those empty namespaces like in paragraph and table. I want to get rid of them so that those elements are just as they are without any namespaces but the div element should retain the namespace.

EDIT: I also would like to get rid of the attributes (including their values) for all elements under text. So that final output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Test>
    <section>
        <id extension="something" root="testRoot"/>

        <text>
      <status value="generated"/>

        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <paragraph>Soemthing</paragraph>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Style</th>
                        <th>Stuff</th>                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
       </text>

    </section>

</Test>
```

Comment: You are asking for two things that contradict each other: in your output, `paragraph` is a child of `div` - and `div` declares the `xhtml` namespace as the default namespace. If you remove the no-namespace declaration from `paragraph`, it will inherit the default namespace from its parent. -- P.S. Your stylesheet says version 1.0 - but `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` is only allowed in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:c="urn:hl7-org:v3"
exclude-result-prefixes="c">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="xhtml" >
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="xhtml"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" mode="#all">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c:section/c:text">
    <text>
        <status value="generated"/>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="xhtml"/>
        </div>
    </text>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will place all descendants of `div` into the same `xhtml` namespace as their ancestor - resulting in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
   <section>
      <id extension="something" root="testRoot"/>
      <text>
         <status value="generated"/>
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <paragraph styleCode="somestyle">Soemthing</paragraph>
            <table>
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th styleCode="styled">Style</th>
                     <th>Stuff</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
         </div>
      </text>
   </section>
</Test>
```

Note that this is not valid XHTML markup.

---

### Edit

> I also would like to get rid of the attributes (including their
>   values) for all elements under text.

Well, then don't apply templates to them:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:c="urn:hl7-org:v3"
exclude-result-prefixes="c">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="xhtml" >
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="xhtml"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c:section/c:text">
    <text>
        <status value="generated"/>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="xhtml"/>
        </div>
    </text>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help. That is what I wanted. Just to understand, we are adding the mode to process only those node with xhtml ns. Mode = '#all for attributes means all attributes should be processed with that template. But if I think about it carefully, I don't get very well why the mode = xhtml template only adds ns to the parent element? The template seems to my understanding to say create the elements and then add xhtml ns, so why does it only do so for the parent div element? Not that I am complaining since the current result is my desired one, but just wanted to understand.

Comment: The xslt version issue doesn't seem to be a problem in my case. In my case, whether I write `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"` or `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"` the result is the same. That is why I didn't know that `#all` is only for xsl 2.0 because I was getting the desired result anyway although my stylesheet says 1.0. I am using a java program that uses Saxon xslt processor.

Comment: "*I don't get very well why the mode = xhtml template only adds ns to the parent element?*" It places **every** processed element in the `xhtml` namespace - but it only declares the namespace once.  As I said in my initial comment: a default namespace is inherited by the descendants.

Comment: "*although my stylesheet says 1.0. I am using a java program that uses Saxon xslt processor.*" You should be aware that processing an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor is performed in *compatibility mode* - which may have some implications.

Comment: Now, I have the problem of getting rid of all those attributes. I had a template that was matching all attributes under text element and getting rid of them, namely `c:text//@*` but it no longer works. I guess due to the change in namespace or something. But now regardless of what I do, they seem to be always there.

Comment: I guess you want to remove the `mode="#all"` part from the template matching `@*`.

Comment: Thanks. Has the desired effect of removing the attributes; unfortunately, has also the undesired effect of including the attribute values inside the elements, so that you get `<paragraph>somestyleSoemthing</paragraph>` instead of `<paragraph>Soemthing</paragraph>` . My hunch is that `<xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>` in the `match = @*` template is to blame but don't know how exactly how I can fix it without causing further side effects.

Comment: You need to amend your question, or post a new one.

Comment: Amended it by adding that I would like to remove the attributes under text elements.

Comment: I meant post your XSLT and the expected result. I got lost trying to read snippets of code in comments and piecing it all together.

Comment: OK, added the wanted output. The XSLT is the same as the last one, also the input xml. The only addition is that I would like the attributes and their values for all elements under text removed.